# Typescript: make one type of one argument dependent on value of other argument

Tags: typescript, generics

Im trying to create a function of which one argument is dependant on the other. I can not make it work and it's starting to drive me crazy. Here's what i'm trying to do:

```
export interface LaneLayout {
  i: number;
  x: number;
  y: number;
  w: number;
  h: number;
  lane_content: string;
  project_id: number;
}

export type Action = "modify" | "create";

export type ModifiedLaneLayout = Omit<
  LaneLayout,
  "project_id" | "lane_content"
>;
export type CreatedLaneLayout = Pick<LaneLayout, "x" | "y">;

export type LayoutType<T extends Action> = T extends "modify"
  ? ModifiedLaneLayout
  : T extends "create"
  ? CreatedLaneLayout
  : never;

export function modifyBox<K extends Action>(
  action: K,
  layout: LayoutType<K>
): void {
  if (action === "modify") {
    layout.h; // property h should exist here
  } else {
    layout.h // property h should not exist here
  }
}
```

In the function, it seems that regardless of the value of action, the type of the layout argument is always CreatedLaneLayout and property h doesn't exist in both cases of the if-statement. What am I missing here?

Comment: BTW, there's an easier way to implement `LayoutType`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCyEAmBLAZt4TAGQEMA7YUxCAV3gF44BvAXwG4AoUSWBZVAMJRgJGIVIUqtBsxYcu4aPCQo4UugBV+AHg1xQYspgDOcAEQBbLHkRm4AH3MBjYaOBmAfHEZMOcOC4iYgBccEJB4uSUJNR0nP5WOLiIoRhJBMRR6jCcLADaGgC6HEA

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to join both arguments together into one object (and also modifyBox will stop being a generic function after this):

```js
type ModifyBoxArgument
  = {action: 'create'; layout: CreatedLaneLayout}
  | {action: 'modify'; layout: ModifiedLaneLayout}

export function modifyBox(arg: ModifyBoxArgument): void {
  if (arg.action === "modify") {
    arg.layout.h; // property h should exist here
  } else {
    arg.layout.h // property h should not exist here
  }
}
```

But remember that you cannot destructure `arg` until you're inside `if`'s body (or in the `else` section), or it will prevent the compiler from tracking the dependency between `action` and `layout` types.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=13&pln=19&pc=23#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgGUyWEIE8IBXeAbwCg5EAuOJCgWwCM0BueuEZq048%20pQey5ReDAO7jhUvgAt5k6XAA2RYAH1sEFMBTMAzjCjIA5urBQIAK2DYYOhABNVIgL61aoSLBwMKRgeACCzggGcAC8cABEbBBuCOik8XAAPgnYUMCYqPG8fuDQ8MGhcACyyakIwG6ExGSU8HEA8mwIMAA8fE0kmORUADR88bYOTi7uGdnxWsR6Bqgo8bQAfLz%20ZUEheADCeQUNAy1UsXAACgjYANY9Z0OtIwkgcwnpW747gRV45xgABV9j0gXBQKs3CY4BEYFEkBtLuDIUZoQkkik0usGAB%20aq1dD1RraQF8ZgokBQmHxXL5Qp8fFHemnUnPKjkljAABuIlo-wJWNIACEICAwlBLOwjDA%20HFqDh4QZmAByOknFXcTTsmDMZknEnNHU%20BjZBWRZVwFWY1KkTXa4a6wV1VlGx0%20EoBeDoChIC1IOA2tKikAACkwkuYNSFIYlUrYMoAlMxuRB3HA6AxUnBw5KAHSKhGxGJxRKE9KJjN8BgRyx5rSOvNKLUAehbcEmoVgpDgSjgJiUlA0bghIAQZl7aGAfC8EI0JjwmYYcFr9Z1TbgbY7di7wV7-cHFGHLAg8FA4-gSinM9oXiAA)